# How Rich Menu in Prestashop 1.6 is feeded?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I would like to know how to edit rich menu in Prestashop 1.6.

I have seen `Horizontal Top Menu` Module in administration.
But the `Rich Menu` module in administration is not free, and in the example of Prestashop 1.6beta the rich menu is present.

Where is it configured ? Which module ?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a post on prestashop forum that explains what I want to know : http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/300692-rich-menu-and-version-16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Upload thumbnails under the main category: http://puu.sh/6g8vp.jpg
- They are going to be displayed as a rich menu on the FO: http://puu.sh/6g8yc.jpg

It is just a simple rich menu.